# Highchart: show seconday y-axis tick positions 0 to 12

Tags: highcharts

I'm outputting a series of high charts on a page. In this chart used secondary y-axis for essay. I used

```
tickPositions: [0,3,6,9,12]
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/AT32j/3/) but in that chart scales are stretched and displayed 3,12 scales only.

How to display secondary y-axis within this tick-positions (0,3,6,9,12)?

Comment: Hi. Just edited your question so it's easier to be read by other users. A not sure, possibly there got something lost in the end of your question in version 1 (the link looked strange). If so, please add it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- remove `linkedTo` as wergeld said
- disable `alignTicks` to make axes independent

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AT32j/8/

Refs:

- [linkedTo](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.linkedTo)
- [alignTicks](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks)

Comment: ya it's good but i want to start secondary y-axis 0 equal to primary y-axis 0.because left side 6 scale came but right side 5 scales came. is this possible?

Comment: It should be possible by this plugin: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/6/Crossing-Specific-Values ( by default it's not possible to make it 'autoscale' ).

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have [`linkedTo`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.linkedTo) set. Per the documentation:

> When an axis is linked to a master axis, it will take the same
>   extremes as the master, but as assigned by min or max or by
>   setExtremes.

So it is using the same scale as your yAxis[0].

Comment: removed linkedT0,but the axis start at 0 end at 14.i want secondary y-axis 0 to 12.primary and secondary axis should start with same line,but secondary axis like as(0 ,3, 6, 9, 12).is there any way to accomplish this? http://jsfiddle.net/AT32j/7/